# how to get Video id from url of youtube in php and cakephp

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, youtube, cakephp-1.3

how to get Video id from url of youtube in php  and cakephp

i have this url

```
http://youtu.be/JaFfJN_iKdA
```

how to get video id from it by regular expression

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$url = "http://youtu.be/JaFfJN_iKdA";
if (preg_match('%(?:youtube\.com/(?:user/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $result)) {
    $video_id = $result[1];
}
```

That will work for a bunch of common YT URL formats including the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regular expressions, you could use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
<?php
$url = parse_url("http://youtu.be/JaFfJN_iKdA");
echo substr($url["path"], 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the library of
http://autoembed.com/
it also covers 100 other video portals

Answer (score 0):

after hard working ,i make a function for getting youtube info

```
function getYoutubeThumbnail($url)
{
    if(preg_match('![?&]{1}v=([^&]+)!', $url . '&', $m))
    {
        $videoid = $m[1];
    }
    else if(preg_match('~/v/([0-9a-z_]+)~i', $url, $m))
    {
        $videoid = $m[1];
    }
/*  else if (preg_match('%(?:youtube\.com/(?:user/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $result)) 
    {
        $video_id = $result[1];
    }*/
    $youtube_thumbnail = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $videoid . '/default.jpg';

    $c = curl_init();

    $url = trim($url);

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $contents = curl_exec($c);

    curl_close($c);


    $feed = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$videoid;

    $newInfo = trim(@file_get_contents($feed));

    preg_match('/<media:title(.*?)<\/media:title>/', $newInfo, $result);

    $title = strip_tags($result[0]);

    preg_match('/<media:keywords(.*?)<\/media:keywords>/', $newInfo, $result);

     $desc = strip_tags(str_replace(",", "", $result[0]));

     //embed path
     $embed_path = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$videoid;



    $youtube_info = array('videoid' => $videoid,'title' => $title, 'description' => $desc,'youtube_thumbnail' => $youtube_thumbnail,'embed_path' => $embed_path) ;

    return $youtube_info;

}
```